# ftp connection issue in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp, filezilla

```
       $this->load->library('ftp');

        $config['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';
        $config['username'] = 'username';
        $config['password'] = 'password';
        $config['passive']  = FALSE;
        $config['debug']    = FALSE;
        $config['port'] = 21;

        $this->ftp->connect($config);

        $destination = '/assets/'.$file_name;

        //Upload file to the remote server
        $this->ftp->upload($source, ".".$destination, 'ascii', 0775);

        //Close FTP connection
        $this->ftp->close();
```

This above configurations are used and filezilla FTP server is installed on local  windows PC.

```
if (FALSE === ($this->conn_id = @ftp_connect($this->hostname, $this->port))){
    if ($this->debug === TRUE){
            $this->_error('ftp_unable_to_connect');
    }
 return FALSE;}
```

Program stops in the first condition and $this->conn_id gives null value. There is no any error given. How could I connect to the server? Is there any addition configurations to be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might not have errors because of `@` at the beginning of `ftp_connect`. According to the documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php):

> PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.

Try without the dot and then check if any errors appear.

Comment: The issue is sorted. The error was with the wamp server which is not FTP enabled.